# React child component does not rerender after parent component update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a main parent component (`DataTableComponent`) which is a data table and have a large set of data. And in that data table I have edit buttons to each row. And then after user click on edit button I pass the respective data to a function then I push to another component (`EditComponent`) using `react-router-dom useHistory` hook and with that I pass the data. Functions look like this.

```
const redirectToEditPage = (data) => {
        push({
            pathname: '/edit',
            state: {
                data
            }
        })
    }
```

And in the `EditComponent`, there's a form which sets the initial data which receive as props from the `DataTableComponent`. In a `useEffect` hook call I process some data (I create image `File` objects using image links and then set it to a `setState` which is initialized as an empty array) received from props. And along with that form in the `EditComponent`, there's also one other child component (`ImagePicker`) which render some images. And to this `ImagePicker` component I pass the processed image Files array as a prop. And in the first initial render of the `EditComponent`, `ImagePicker` component render the images that I passed as props nicely. But after clicking back button on web browser which goes back to the `DataTableComponent` and then selecting another table row and cliking edit button on the table which push to the `EditComponent` again, it render the other data on the form in the `EditComponent` as expected but it does not render any image files on the child component (`ImagePicker`)

**EditComponent**

```
const EditComponent = ({data}) => {
    const [imageFiles, setImageFiles] = useState([])

const imageFilesInitialStateFunc = () => {
    const tempArr = []
    tempArr.push({sequence: 0, image: data.image?.mainImage})
    const productAdditionalImages = data.image?.productAdditionalImageList
    if (productAdditionalImages.length > 0) {
        productAdditionalImages.map((image) => {
            const obj = {sequence: image.sequence, image: image.additionalImage}
            tempArr.push(obj)
        })
    }
    return tempArr
}

const convertImageUrlToFiles = (files) => {
    const tempFiles = []
    files.map((file) => {
        const imageUrl = constructMediaCDNUrl(`product_images/${file.image}`, 200)
        toDataURL(imageUrl)
            .then(dataUrl => {
                // console.log('Base64 Url', dataUrl)
                const fileData = dataURLtoFile(dataUrl, file.image);
                // console.log("JavaScript File Object", fileData)
                tempFiles.push(fileData)
            })
    })
    setImageFiles(tempFiles)
}


    useEffect(() => {
        const initialImageFiles = imageFilesInitialStateFunc()
        convertImageUrlToFiles(initialImageFiles)

        return () => {
            console.log('pressed back')
        }
    }, [])

    return (
       // form

       
       <ImagePicker key={imageFiles} files={imageFiles} setFiles={setImageFiles}/>

    )

}
```

**ImagePicker Component**

```
const ImagePicker = ({files, setFiles}) => {

return (
 <div>
  {files.length > 0 ? ( 
    {files.map((file, index) => (
      <img key={index} src={URL.createObjectURL(file)} alt={file.name} className="product-images img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded mb-1" />
    ))

  ) : <div>Loading...</div>
 </div>
)

}
```

After the first render when user goes back to `DataTableComponent` by clicking back button and then selecting another table row and clicking edit button which goes to `EditComponent`, then all other data render as expected but only `ImagePicker` component is displayed as `Loading...`

Answer (score 0):

In EditComponent, try modifying the useEffect as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const initialImageFiles = imageFilesInitialStateFunc()
    convertImageUrlToFiles(initialImageFiles)

    return () => {
        console.log('pressed back')
    }
}, [data, data.image])
```